# Java EE sample applications

Tags: jakarta-ee

After the Oracle takeover of Sun and the changes at java.net, I am no longer able to find any official samples of Java EE applications. The [Blueprints](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/blueprints/index.html) and [Glassfish Samples](http://glassfish-samples.java.net/) sites still exist, but links from them are all dead.

Is there anywhere I'm overlooking? I'm interested in the Pet Store application in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup... it looks like no one has updated the links that went into *.dev.java.net in the huge cache of documents that Oracle acquired when they acquired Sun.

The site isn't on-line... but the code for it is... if that makes sense.

The Blueprints are at http://java.net/projects/blueprints/...

The PetStore is at http://java.net/projects/petstore.

A useful 'source root' is probably this: http://java.net/projects/petstore/sources/svn/show/trunk.

The ws subdirectory is the WorkSpace (where the code is) and the www directory has the HTML/CSS/.js source of the website.

Comment: Thanks! In addition to these, it looks like the "Java EE Code Samples & Apps" are useful: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/javaee5-jsp-142110.html

Answer (score 0):

Because it was moved on http://kenai.com/ if I recall correctly.